# How to Set Default value in spinner at first position?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Below is my code from which I am populating state in spinner from sqlite and it is working perfect. Now what I want that I want to add "Select State" hardcoded at first position. How can I achieve this ?

```
 try {
            ArrayList<String> state_array = new ArrayList<String>();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nCtgId = 6", null);


            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //assing values
                    String stateID = cursor.getString(0);
                    String stateName = cursor.getString(1);
                    stateData = stateName;
                    state_array.add(stateData);


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, state_array);
            spnState.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
            cursor.close();
            spnState.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    state = spnState.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo FROM CodeMaster where cCodeName = '" + state + "'", null);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            //assing values
                            stateCodeId = cursor.getString(0);

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }


            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
try {
            ArrayList<String> state_array = new ArrayList<String>();
           state_array.add("Select State");

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nSerialNo as _id,cCodeName FROM CodeMaster where nCtgId = 6", null);


            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    //assing values
                    String stateID = cursor.getString(0);
                    String stateName = cursor.getString(1);
                    stateData = stateName;
                    state_array.add(stateData);


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: Hi brahmy. Thanks for your answer. I am populating multiple spinner same like above. when I select state from above code then I want populate city in another spinner from sqlite from same table. I doing same thing like above but it is not populating city in another spinner. when I give hard coded ID of any state then its give me list of cities in spinner. It means my city spinner not refreshing when I am selecting state. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: bro use the following condition in the link http://pastebin.com/gGsp2JDB

Answer (score 0):

**state_array.add(0, "Select State");**
ArrayAdapter my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, state_array);
spnState.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
cursor.close();